# TYPO3 7.6: disable fe_typo_user cookie

Tags: cookies, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

How can I deactivate the fe_typo_user cookie in TYPO3 7.6. I don't use fe_login or other data stored in sessions on this website, but the cookie is set. The website was updated from an earlier TYPO3 version. In [this issue](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/84866#note-3) another user had the same problem with an updated version - as solution he obviously used a fresh installation of TYPO3.

Isn't there another way to deactivate this cookie if not used? In earlier versions it worked with

```
["FE"]["dontSetCookie"] = 1
```

but in 7.6. obviously not anymore.

**Edit:**
The cookie is set new. I deleted it in chrome developer tools. You could check [this webiste](https://netactive.de). I use powermail for contact forms, but as far as I know it doesn't set cookies. For tracking Piwik/Matomo is used, but it has it's own cookies "outside" of TYPO3. Conditions aren't used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of powermail are you using?
Since v6.0 the session-spam-check is disabled by default.

From release notes:

> Task: Disable session-spam-check by default (to prevent generating a cookie)

Comment: Unfortunately a very old version - 3.9.0. But thanks for the hint, in fact powermail sets the session. I deactivated the extension and the cookie isn't set anymore. I will update the TYPO3 and powermail!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the cookie is set new?

You need to identify where you have user-dependent configuration which might set the cookie. 
Do you have forms or interactive elements in the site?
Do you have conditions in your configuration?
Do you use tracking tools?

Comment: Yes, the cookie is set new. See edit in my question.